# System.data.services.client n/a in metro style apps?

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-metro

I wish to add the BingSearchContainer ( from http://datamarket.azure.com/ ) and I need to add the system.data.services.client namespace, however even though I can see it appearing in the .NET for Metro style apps reference if I check for its existence in the objectbrowser , I simply cannot add it. Does anyone have some similar experiences?

regards

Answer (score 0):

I recall having to do something similar for my project when I started developing it.   However, I have since then updated both my installation of Windows 8 and  VS 2012.  Now, when I go to "Add refereces," I see no option to add or remove any references for my Metro app.  Do you need to add a service reference?  Maybe this will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the BingSearchContainer and found it to be too much of a black box for my taste. Try connecting to the bing search using `RestSharp` a lightweight RESTful webservice wrapper than can handle this simply -- here is an example of an image search using RestSharp with the Bing API:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/");
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(_key, _key); //_key is your unencrypted marketplace api key

var request = new RestRequest(String.Format("Image?Query='{0}'&Market='en-US'&Adult='Strict'&ImageFilters='Size:Small'&$top={1}&$skip={2}", query, rpp, page * rpp), Method.GET);

var json = client.Execute(request).Content;
```

If you want to deserialize the json into a strongly typed class, use the `JsonConvert.Deserialize<T>(string json)` method available in the `NewtonSoft` JSON open source library.

Hope this helps.